# How to solve a error when I call the method [self somemethod]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have this code:

```
// .m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self addToArray];
}

- (void)addToArray {
    NSString *stringA;
    [stringA isEqualToString:@"door"];
    NSString *stringB;
    [stringB isEqualToString:textField.text];
    [array addObject:stringA];
    if ([stringA isEqual:stringB]) {
        [stringA isEqual:nil];
        [tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        [array addObject:stringB];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

When I call the method addToArray it keeps returning me an error called `Thread 1: Program recived signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"`, and the debugger output says : `Single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend, which has no line number information.` at the line `[self addToArray]`. Any idea of how to solve it? I have wasted to much time with it, please help me!

Comment: And the code shows you create an array to a local variable without showing how addToArray has any chance to access it??

Comment: Ok, I have uploaded the addToArray code. I can't see any bug, however maybe you will see something.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with your code, but one big problem is that you are sending messages to uninitialized objects (stringA and stringB)

Answer (score 2):

As was said by others, `array` should be an instance variable or property of the class, declared in the `.h` file:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Or, without ARC:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Now you `@synthesize array;` in your implementation file and can access it from anywhere. Then you can do:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self addToArray];
}
```

You seem to assume that `isEqualToString` does an assignment. It doesn't, it checks strings for (textual) equality. Try this:

```
- (void) addToArray
{
    NSString *stringA = @"door";
    NSString *stringB = textField.text;
    [array addObject: stringA];
    if (![stringA isEqualToString: stringB])
        [array addObject: stringB];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two variables are uninitialized and will cause you big problems:

```
NSString *stringA;
[stringA isEqualToString:@"door"];
NSString *stringB;
[stringB isEqualToString:textField.text];
```

You have not assigned anything to either stringA or stringB. Besides the result of your call to isEqualToString is never used.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I can notice in your code:

1) Make `array` a class variable, so you can access it from your `-[addToArray]` method. Better do this in your .h file, for example:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
@private
// ...skipped...
   NSMutableArray * array;
// ...rest of class skipped...
}
@end
```

Then, in your .m file the method should look like this:

```
// .m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self addToArray];
}
```

And don't forget to release the array:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [array release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

2) Do not mess up `-[NSString isEqualToString:]` method with simple assigment to a variable. So in your `-[addToArray]` method, for example, replace this:

```
NSString *stringA;
[stringA isEqualToString:@"door"];
```

with this:

```
NSString *stringA = @"door";
```

And this:

```
NSString *stringB;    
[stringB isEqualToString:textField.text];
```

with this:

```
NSString *stringB = textField.text;
```

3) Check the logic of `-[addToArray]` method - it is not very clear what are you going achieve.